# Le fait que ça va aller mal, ça me rend peureux

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, futur

Comment traduire le titre en utilisant le mot "craindre":

Crainde + "ne" + subjonctif, donc:

> Je crains que ça ne va donner des problèmes.

=> correcte : le subjonctif futur n'existe pas.

> Je crains que ça n'aille donner de problèmes.

=> correcte : le subjonctif de "(il) va" est "qu'(il) aille".

Lequel est correcte?

Comment: *Ne* n'est pas nécessaire, sa présence ne change rien au sens de la phrase.  On peut dire « je crains que ça donne des problèmes » ou « je crains que ça ne donne des problèmes ».  Le subjonctif exprimant un fait qui n'est pas réel aucun besoin du futur. Si vraiment on veut un futur c'est dans la principale qu'il faut le mettre. Par exemple : « je craindrai que ça donne des problèmes ».

Answer (score 1):

*Ça me rend peureux* n'est probablement pas ce que tu veux dire. Être peureux, c'est un trait de caractère, pas quelque chose qui arrive à cause d'un fait ou d'une crainte précise. Ici, c'est probablement *ça me fait peur* que tu veux dire.

D'autre part *donner* est possible mais n'est pas le verbe le plus habituel avant *des problèmes*. Voici quelques tournures plus idiomatiques :

> *Je crains que ça ne pose des problèmes.*
> *Je crains que ça pose problème.*
> *Je crains que ça ne cause des problèmes*.
> *Je crains que ça tourne mal.*

Enfin, si la cause est une certitude, ce qui semble être le cas d'après la phrase du titre, tu ne peux pas utiliser *craindre* qui implique un doute. Dans ce cas, *j'ai peur* est un choix possible :

> ***j'ai peur car ça va mal tourner***.

Answer (score -1):

- Je crains que ça ne va donner des problèmes.

Cet usage est incorrect, « ne » ne peut pas être utilisé dans cette construction. Par exemple, les verbes couramment utilisés « donner » et  « faire » ne sont jamais construits de cette façon ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que+%C3%A7a+ne+va+donner%2Cque+%C3%A7a+ne+va+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)).

C'est exact, le futur du subjonctif n'existe pas.

Le présent du subjonctif de « aller » à la troisième personne du singulier est bien « aille », mais dans la phrases dans laquelle on trouve ce verbe n'est pas grammaticale ni idiomatique lorsque rendue grammaticale.

- Je crains que ça n'aille donner de problèmes. (*ni grammatical ni idiomatique*)
- Je crains que ça aille donner de**s** problèmes. (*pas idiomatique*)
- Je crains que ça  donne des problèmes. (*correct*)

La construction  suivante avec le subjonctif est aussi correcte.

- Je crains que ça ne donne des problèmes.

On trouve un cas de cet usage d'« aller », mais l'imparfait est le temps nécessaire ; de plus la conjonction « si » doit se trouver dans la construction, qui doit être interrogative.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller)) c) [À l'imp., précédé de *si* cond.-interr. (**pour marquer une action imminente redoutée**)]
> ♦ ... pour remonter sans chandelle, si j'allais me tromper de porte? H. Pourrat, Gaspard des montagnes,À la belle bergère, 1925, p. 240.

- Il était en colère… s'il allait nous faire des histoires?